# Displaying youtube video in django 1.8 by passing id as CharField

Tags: python, django, youtube

I've been trying to display youtube videos by passing the video id in a class and replacing the value in a template.But it doesn't seem to be happening.
 My `models.py`

from django.db import models

```
class Rockinfo(models.Model):
   rock_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="ac/dc")
   rock_img = models.ImageField(upload_to="%Y/%m/%d",default="1992/08/92")
   rank = models.IntegerField(default=0)


def __str__(self):              
    return self.rock_name


class Rockvids(models.Model):
   rockername = models.ForeignKey(Rockinfo)
   vid_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="Z7JgY9zezj4")
   vid_name = models.CharField(max_length=300,default="Something Inside Me")
   vid_singer_name = models.CharField(max_length=300,default="Jonathan Reyes Myers")

def __str__(self):
    return self.vid_id
```

my `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Rockinfo, Rockvids

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Rockvids
  extra = 10

class RockinfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  fieldsets = [
  ('The Fucking Band',               {'fields': ['rock_name']}),
  ('Image', {'fields': ['rock_img']}),
]
inlines = [ChoiceInline]  
list_display = ('rock_name', 'rock_img')
list_filter = ['rank']
search_fields = ['rock_name']


admin.site.register(Rockinfo, RockinfoAdmin)
```

my application's `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
   url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

My application's `views.py` file

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from .models import Rockvids, Rockinfo


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
   template_name = 'rockinglist/index.html'
   context_object_name = 'latest_rockinfo_list'

   def get_queryset(self):
    return Rockinfo.objects.order_by('-rank')[:50]


   class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Rockinfo
    template_name = 'rockinglist/detail.html'
```

`index.html` file

```
 {% if latest_rockinfo_list %}
 <ul>
 {% for rockinfo in latest_rockinfo_list %}
 <h1>{{ rockinfo.rock_name }}</a></li>
 <img src="img\{{ rockinfo.rock_img }}" alt="ac/dc">
 {% endfor %}
 </ul>
 {% else %}
 <p>No</p>
 {% endif %}
```

`detail.html` file

```
<h1>{{ rockinfo.rock_name }}</h1>
{% for choice in rockinfo.rockvids_set.all %}
<img id="hide" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{ rockvids.vid_id   }}/hqdefault.jpg" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ rockvids.vid_id }}?autoplay=1" width="480" height="300"/>


{% endfor %}
```

I have been trying to display all the youtube videos once the user clicks on the image by using the videos id passed in `Rockvids`class but there seems to be some error in the loop. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have some javascript that accesses the "data-video" attribute you've created?

Comment: Yes.But the loop in `details.html` is not functioning properly because I added an `h2` tag to check if it displays but it didn't. Even without the JS, it should display something.

Comment: The image is showing, but no video plays?  Or is the problem something else?

Comment: No.In the index page I have an image and a name.When I click on the image it is supposed to go to `details.html` and display the name and the 10 videos associated with it.But on clicking the image it only shows the name and not the videos by which I'm guessing it doesn't enter the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template loop, you've defined the object as `choice`.  Just refer to it that way rather than using `rockvids`.  See below.

```
{% for choice in rockinfo.rockvids_set.all %}
<img id="hide" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{ choice.vid_id   }}/hqdefault.jpg" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ choice.vid_id }}?autoplay=1" width="480" height="300"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Since you'll have multiple images, you probably want to change `id="hide"` to `class="hide"` as well, since there should only be one element with a given `id` on a page.

Comment: Tried this. But it doesn't work.I even tried replacing `choice` with `rockvids` everywhere but that doesn't work either.

Comment: There's some mistake at the for loop itself because it doesn't enter the loop.

Comment: If you look at the page source, are any of the `<img>` tags there, and just not displaying?  (Use View Source or Page Source from your browser's menu.)

Comment: No.Only the `h1` tag that I used in`detail.html` to display name is there. No presence of anything inside the for loop.

Comment: Your loop syntax, at least as posted here, looks fine.  `{% for choice in rockinfo.rockvids_set.all %}` If the name is showing up in the <h1> tag, then the object is being correctly passed to the template.  Double check that there are indeed some rockvids that have their `rockername` set to the `Rockinfo` instance you're trying.  One reason for nothing showing up is that the `rockinfo.rockvids_set.all` is empty.

Comment: To test if the loop is working, add an `{% empty %}` clause to your loop: `{% for choice ... %} <img.../> {% empty %} No videos for this rocker {% endfor %}`

Comment: Yes! the `{% empty %}` clause worked. the html page now shows the name followed by ` No videos for this rocker` . But what does this mean? Is the problem with the `img` tag then? Because I added an `h1` tag before the empty clause in the loop and that didn't display either.

Comment: It means that there are no items in the `rockinfo.rockvids_set.all`.  Again, check in the admin that there are some videos that have the correct ForeignKey, and/or check your typing in the template.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7di5r9  http://prntscr.com/7di59k These are screenshots of my django admin and details.html. Both seem to be fine. The rockvids are all there. Anything else that I should check?

Comment: Found the issue. The `rockinfo.rockvids_set.all` was in fact empty. I was trying to execute with default values. When I added different values, it worked.Thanks.